# python3: what exactly does `**` operator does

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

```
def func(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
```

Are these two function calls identical?

```
d = {'id':1, 'name':'qwerty', 'dtype':3}
func1(**d)
func1(id=1, name='qwerty', dtype=3)
```

As far I understand, with a formal parameter in the form `**arg`, it receives a dictionary, while the formal parameter as `*arg` yields the tuple.

What is actually happening behind `**kwargs`?

Comment: Have a look at [What is the purpose and use of \*\*kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/what-is-the-purpose-and-use-of-kwargs)

Comment: @khelwood, thanks for link. It explains everything I wanted to know about kwargs.

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly as you said.

> **kwargs allows you to pass keyworded variable length of arguments to a function.
>
> You should use **kwargs if you want to handle named arguments in a
>   function.

`**` takes a dictionary and "spreads" it to a function as keyword (named) params.